# forEach array javascript incomplete

Tags: javascript

UPDATED

I am trying to build an array by calling a callback function and feeding it with values from other arrays.
However, I get only few values and I cannot understand why.

the structure is like:

```
var sortedData = [];

arrayProvidingTheValues.forEach(pushEl,sortedData);
```

and the callback function is

```
function pushEl(element,index) {
   console.log("pushEl called");
   this[index] = element;
}
```

input:

```
saisineArray = {obj1, obj2 obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6};
contratArray = {obj21, obj22 obj23, obj24, obj25, obj26};
intervalNb = 5;
```

expected output

```
 sortedData = {obj1, obj2 obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6,obj21, obj22 obj23, obj24, obj25,obj6,obj26};
```

PS: this is the detailled code to show you in more detail.

```
for (var k = 0; k < intervalNb; k++) {
    if (k * interval >= saisineArray.length) {
    } else if ((k + 1) * interval >= saisineArray.length) {
        saisineArray.slice(k * interval, saisineArray.length).forEach(pushEl, sortedData);
    } else {
        saisineArray.slice(k * interval, (k + 1) * interval).forEach(pushEl, sortedData);
    }
    if (k * interval >= contratArray.length) {
    } else if ((k + 1) * interval >= contratArray.length) {
        contratArray.slice(k * interval, contratArray.length).forEach(pushEl, sortedData);
    } else {
        contratArray.slice(k * interval, (k + 1) * interval).forEach(pushEl, sortedData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are not expecting that your `index` values start over at `0` for each new array that is iterated? Please add example input and expected output to show what problem you are facing.

Comment: By the way, you shoudl really look into `concat`. There's no need for `forEach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `this[index] = element;` try `this.push(element);`

What you're doing now is on every execution of `forEach(pushEl)` you are overwriting the `sortedData` array starting from index 0.